# How to go about changing the tint color of an image?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Sorry for the vague title, I have no idea how to really ask this question to be honest so I'll describe what I'm trying to do

I'm attempting to make an app where users can change the colors of different parts of a car. They can change the door for instance to a green as shown, or any other color they wish. They would then be able to change the color of the hood, or the roof, etc.

I've thought about having seperate images for each component and then lining them up to match. However this seems practically impossible when it comes to different screen sizes and scales. I also thought about making a blanket white image, and then creating views over the top with the selected color.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could possibly approach this?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know about the performance of this. But, how about, an overlay of the different parts of the car, but using the same size of the whole car. For example, you have the image of the whole car, and erase all but the door. In other image, you erase all but the hood. If you lay one image above another, it will make the whole car, and the size of the screen will not affect you, because all the images will have the same size. 
Then you can use the tint style to change the color of each layer.

Comment: That sounds like a great solution. I'm only going to be modifying about a dozen components so hoping performance shouldn't be too bad. Thanks for responding!